# Why is convolution the integral of product of two functions?

Tags: integration, convolution

I am studying the convolution operation and I have been told that when we calculate the convolution of two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, we are actually calculate "the area under the function $f(\tau)$ weighted by the weighting function $g(t-\tau)$". However, I could not understand why the formula of convolution is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau)g(t-\tau) \,dx$. To be specific, I don't know why the product of the two functions are calculating the area under the two function.

For example, the area under these two functions

[image: first pic]

Should be the same as the area under these two functions

[image]

But the product of these two functions are scaled by 1.5. Why does the integral product of these two functions represent the area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the convolution isn't “the area under two functions”.

The convolution, as you cited, can be understood as an area under a function weighted by another function. The word “weighted” is what describes multiplication.

The area under a blue function consists of 3 areas. Orange function defines the weight (density) of those areas: (1) and (3) has density 0, (2) has density 1.5, so the result is:
$$
C = 1×0 + 1×1.5 + 1×0 = 1.5
$$

[image]